# Meta_Query with multi select values

Tags: meta-query

I have the following:

```
$int_args = array(
              'post_type' => 'intervention',
              'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                  'key' => 'linked_outcomes_array',
                  'value' => $outcome_ID,
                  'compare' => 'IN'
                )
              )
             );
```

$outcome_ID is an array where it could be 'a,b,c' or 'ab' or 'ab, ac' etc.

Any idea how I would accomplish return the posts of any combination of outcome_IDs?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Please check once **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789776/wordpress-meta-query-an-array-of-values-when-metadata-to-compare-is-serialized-a**

Comment: I believe that what I was trying to achieve was not possible using this methodology due to the number of 'value' permutations. I have since found another working solution to my problem.